# Titration of C₄H₆O₂

Tags: homework, metal, titration

$\ce{C4H6O2}$ (10.75 g) was dissolved in water (250 cm<sup>3</sup>) and then a 20 cm<sup>3</sup> sample was titrated against an alkali metal hydroxide solution. This required 17.35 cm<sup>3</sup> of the alkali. What was the concentration of the alkali? 
The water was evaporated from the alkali solution (100 cm<sup>3</sup>) to leave a white solid (3.23 g). Identify the alkali metal present.

My working already is that I started by dividing 10.75g by 0.25dm<sup>3</sup> to get 43g/dm<sup>3</sup>. Then divided 43g/dm<sup>3</sup> by the relative formula mass of 86 to get 0.5mol/dm<sup>3</sup>. I did 0.5mol/dm<sup>3</sup>*0.01735dm<sup>3</sup> to get 0.008675mol then divided that by 0.02dm<sup>3</sup> to get 0.0434 mol/dm<sup>3</sup> as the concentration of the alkali. I'm not sure how to proceed from there or know what I have already done is correct.

Comment: What have you tried and where specifically are you experiencing difficulty.  Note, that we are not a homework help site.

Comment: I started by dividing to 10.75 by 0.25 to get 43g/dm3. Then divided 43 by the relative formula mass of 86 to get 0.5mol/dm3. I did 0.5*0.01735 to get 0.008675mol then divided that by 0.02 to get 0.0434 moldm3 as the concentration of the alkali. I'm not sure how to proceed from there or know what I have already done is correct.

Comment: @Zara Edit the question to include your calculations that you have shown in the above comment.

Comment: Attach the units with your numbers. It makes it easier to spot errors.

Answer (score 2):

> My working already is that I started by dividing $10.75g$ by $0.25dm^3$ to get $43g/dm^3$. Then divided $43g/dm^3$ by the relative formula mass of $86 g/mol$to get $0.5mol/dm^3$.

Up to here, you have it correct. The next step is to take $20 mL$ from $250 mL$, which would decrease the amount of acid to titrate. Then you would find the concentration of the base.

Comment: I see my mistake, so 0.5mol/dm3 * 0.02dm3= 0.01mol of acid. Then 0.01mol/0.01735dm3 gives 0.576mol/dm3, the concentration of the alkali.

Comment: So now you go on to the next part. How many moles of salt are in the precipitate and determine the molecule mass from 3.23g of solid.

Comment: How do you find the mol of the salt, wouldn't it be 0.01mol?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: So I divided 3.23g by 0.01mol to obtain the rfm, but that seems wrong as the answer is 323 which seems too high

Comment: of the product of the reaction? its a solution of 100 cm3 which evaporates to 3.23g of solid. there was 43 g/dm3 originally

Comment: My mistake; I misread the question. The solid (3.23 g) comes from 100 mL of just the alkali solution (I thought it was the salt that was formed). So the solid (3.23 g) comes from 100 mL of 0.576M solution. How would you find the molecule mass of the substance?

Comment: so 0.576M * 0.1dm3 gives 0.0576mol, 3.23g/0.0576mol gives 56

Comment: Good, now identify the metal ion from the molecular mass.

Comment: Wouldn't the product be C4H5O2 and the metal ion, but without the metal ion it already has an RFM of 85

Comment: C4H5O2 and the metal ion is in the other solution that you titrated. The 56 g/mol is from the alkali solution.

Comment: That's what I got.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to solve a titration question by equating the meq of acids and base for a neutral condition.

$$moles \space of \space \ce{C4H6O2}=0.5=\frac{10.75*1000}{250*86}$$
 $$meq \space of \space \ce{C4H6O2}= 500$$
$$meq \space of \space \ce{C4H6O2} in \space 0.02 l=500*0.02=10$$ 
$$\therefore$$
$$meq \space of \space alkali= 10$$
The alkali is sodium, as it give a white ppt and the base was NaOH
$$moles \space of \space \ce{NaOH}=0.01=conc*volume$$
$$conc \space of \space \ce{NaOH}=\frac{0.01}{17.35}*1000=0.576$$
$$\therefore$$
The concentration is 0.576M

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot more sense now, do you have any idea how to identify the alkali metal as I have no idea where to start

Comment: Your first line has a mistake. You are not finding the moles of acid, but the concentration of the acid. Please attach units and you will see that it is a concentration, not moles..

Comment: Yeah it's the molar concentration or the number or moles in 1l don't worry it's perfectly correct

Comment: The numbers are correct, but without the units, it's wrong.